# Navigation Container works in production of Expo go, but not in TestFlight App store connect

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, testflight, react-navigation-stack

I have build a react native expo app. This app works perfectly fine in production. When I run this app on my local computer with `npm start` and connect it with an expo go application on my phone, The app is working perfectly. Now I want to upload this app on app store so I created the build on expo.dev and used the following command to make a build for this app.
`eas build:configure` -> `eas build --platform ios` -> `eas submit -p ios --latest`

I have implemented my credentials of appleId, ascAppID and appleTeamId. and once I upload the build on testflight, it successfully upload the build. After I download the app from testflight, it just shows me a blank white screen instead of showing me a Navigation Container.

my code for app.js is as follows :

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

// // Navigator
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack"
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

// // React Components
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { firebase } from './config';

// // Screens and Pages
import { Login, SignUp, Welcome} from "./screens";

// // Navigation Containers
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

// App Layout 
export default function App() {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  function handleAuthStateChanged(user){
    setUser(user);
    if(initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(handleAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber;
  }, []);

  if(initializing) return null;
  
  if(!user){
    return (
      <NavigationContainer style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName='Welcome'
        >
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Welcome"
            component={Welcome}
            options={{
              headerShown: false
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
            options={{
              headerShown: false
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignUp"
            component={SignUp}
            options={{
              headerShown: false
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
  return({
     <View>
       <Text>Something went wrong</Text>
     </View>
  });
}
```

I also checked if I imported proper dependencies and checked again but the same problem occurred. This is my dependencies from package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.7",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.23.3",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-checkbox": "^2.3.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "stripe": "^12.12.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
```

I also tried removing the navigation container and just adding a normal view of my welcome screen and that worked perfectly for both production and build on testflight.

```
export default function App() {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  function handleAuthStateChanged(user){
    setUser(user);
    if(initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(handleAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber;
  }, []);

  if(initializing) return null;
  
  if(!user){
    return (
      < Welcome />
    );
  }
  return({
     <View>
       <Text>Something went wrong</Text>
     </View>
  });
}
```

so now I am kind of confused as to why the navigation container is not working in the build for testflight. I debuged and tried everything but nothing worked. I googled if navigation container is not working for testflight but nothing came up. Please help me with my problem.

Thank you in advance and if you need more information, please let me know.

Tried uploading the build and testing on testflight so that I can upload my app on app store but the app from testflight shows a blank white screen as my production in expo go shows that my app is working perfectly without any errors.

I am expecting to design a navigation for my app which first goes to Welcome screen, there are buttons to direct the user to either sign up screen or login screen accordingly. But The app is only showing a blank white screen.

Comment: I also added an alert in the welcome.js to know if that react component is called, and I got an alert but still I can't see the view of welcome screen.

Comment: Correction : the code doesn’t break because of Navigation Container but for Stack.Navigator